# How can I hide unselected (web part connection) list items?

Tags: javascript, list-item, html-form-web-part, connection-filters

Team,

**Scenario:**

I have two web parts that are connected with a connection filter. When I select an item in list A, related items in list B are filtered. Hooray!

But list A is really long, so when an item is selected in list A, I would like to hide all the unselected list A items.

I currently have a HTML Form Web Part which I use to filter out different types of list A items. Which allows me to select from a drop down list, apply a filter, and a button to clear the filter (reload the window).

```
<div class="column_left" style="align:center">
 <div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_">
    <select name="Team">
        <option value=""> Select Team </option>
        <option value="Change Management"> Change Management </option>
        <option value="Client Delivery"> Client Delivery </option>
        <option value="Incident Management"> Incident Management </option>
        <option value="Network Management Center"> Network Management Center </option>
        <option value="OBTAC Cloud&DC"> OBTAC Cloud&DC </option>
        <option value="OBTAC UC&CC"> OBTAC UC&CC </option>
        <option value="OBTAC Network&Security"> OBTAC Network&Security </option>
        <option value="Problem Management"> Problem Management </option>
        <option value="Professional Services"> Professional Services </option>
        <option value="Service Desk"> Service Desk </option>
        <option value="Singtel/NCS"> Singtel/NCS </option>
    </select>
    </br>
    <input type="button" value="Apply Filter" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/>
 <input onclick="window.location.href=window.location.href" type="button" value="Clear Filter"/>  
 </div> 
</div>
```

I understand that "row.style.display = 'none';" can be used to hide rows. I have a piece of code that loops through a list and checks the date and hides list items that do not match specific date criteria.

I think I could do something similar, but in order for it to work I need to know how I can check which list item has been selected in a web part connection filter. Any idea what to check for?

So what I would do is add another button to my HTML FORM web part called "Filter Unselected". When clicked it would loop through list A list items and hide each row that is not selected. In theory this should leave the one item that was selected using the connection filter action.

**UPDATE #1:**

This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632861/how-to-get-the-selected-item-in-a-connected-listviewer-web-part-using-javascript) has code that appeared to help. It detects the right list item ID (elemID), I couldn't get the contents of "selectedImg$" or "linkText" to display (I have poor Javascript skills), but I think I can filter ok with the ID anyway.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowSelectedItems() {

var selectedImg$ = $('img[alt^="Selected"]');
var elemID = selectedImg$.closest('tr').attr('iid').split(',')[1];
var linkText = selectedImg$.closest('tr').find('div#'+elemID).find('a').text();

alert("selectedimg: " + selectedImg$ +"\nelemID: " + elemID + "\nlinkText: " + linkText );

}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Show Selected Items" name="btnShowSelectedItems" id="btnShowSelectedItems" onclick="ShowSelectedItems();" />
```

**UPDATE #2:**

As mentioned in the comments below. I think my solution is to use a HTML Form web part that passes the selection ID parameter through a web part connection. Again, not being proficient at JavaScript, I'm unsure how to pass the value without manually inputting it i.e. pass automatically when button is clicked.

This is what I have so far...**but its not working**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var selectedImg$ = $('img[alt^="Selected"]');
var elemID = selectedImg$.closest('tr').attr('iid').split(',')[1];

</script>

<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_">
<input type="hidden" name="itemSelected" value=elemID/>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/>
</div>
```

And once I've got the filter working, I want to make the button toggle between filtering and clearing using code found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button).

**UPDATE #3:**

Progress... If I put the following code into a HTML form, and connect "itemSelected" to the ID column in list A, then select item ID #7, then click the "GO" button in the HTML form. List A filters item #7 perfectly.

```
<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_">
    <input type="hidden" name="itemSelected" value="7"/>
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/>
</div>
```

The only thing I'm struggling with now is how to pass the value stored in "elemID" below into the value of my HTML Form?

```
var selectedImg$ = $('img[alt^="Selected"]');
var elemID = selectedImg$.closest('tr').attr('iid').split(',')[1];
```

**UPDATE #4:**

Success! I discovered how to move the "*SFSUBMIT*" to the function properly and pass the elemID to the input. Last step is to convert the button into a toggle button so it alternates between being a filter and clearing the filter. I'll be using the code I found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function filterSelected() {
        var selectedImg$ = $('img[alt^="Selected"]');
        var elemID = selectedImg$.closest('tr').attr('iid').split(',')[1];
        document.getElementById("filterButton").value = elemID;
    _SFSUBMIT_;
    }
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="itemSelected" value="" id="filterButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="filterSelected();"/>
```

regards
Michael

Comment: The code given in update section solved your problem or not? What exactly your looking for now?

Comment: Sort of, I think I may have a solution - but I don't know how to code it yet... (step 1) create a HTML Form Web Part (step 2) use something like the code shown here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button to create a button that toggles between two different states (step 3) make state #1 do a _SFSUBMIT_ but instead of selecting from a drop down box, pass the ID value of the selected list item, state #2 is a "clear filter" button to reload the page (step 4) add a connection. Currently stuck at how to pass the ID value to SDSUBMIT without using a dropdown list?

Comment: Have you tried this using OOTB SharePoint List filter web part??

Comment: Unfortunately, my company, for whatever reason, doesn't have filter web parts as an available option.

Answer (score 0):

Team,

I couldn't get the toggle feature working, time/effort/reward ratio wasn't there for me, but I did get the filter working and in the end I have two buttons filter on, filter off. Below is the final result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function filterSelected() {
    var selectedImg$ = $('img[alt^="Selected"]');
    var elemID = selectedImg$.closest('tr').attr('iid').split(',')[1];
    document.getElementById("filterButton").value = elemID;
    _SFSUBMIT_;
    }
</script>

<div align="center">
    <input type="hidden" name="itemSelected" value="" id="filterButton" />
    <input type="button" value="Filter Selected" onclick="filterSelected();" style="font-weight: bold; width: 45%; height: 30px; background-color: #e6e6e6; border-radius: 5px;" />
    <input onclick="window.location.href=window.location.href" type="button" value="Clear Selected" style="font-weight: bold; width: 45%; height: 30px; background-color: #e6e6e6; border-radius: 5px;"/>
</div>
```

regards
Michael